# I Need Code in PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am a starter in PL/SQL and I have a problem.
I have two tables like below:

```
Table_1

Customer           Hometown             Request
-----------------------------------------------
 John               London                Car
 John               London               House
 Michael            Amsterdam             Car
 Michael            Amsterdam           Computer
 Alan               Manchester           Yacht
 Mehmet             Istanbul            Telephone


Table_2

Customer           Hometown             Request
-----------------------------------------------

 Michael            Amsterdam             Car
 Michael            Amsterdam           Computer
 Alan               Manchester           House
 Chris              Liverpool            Telephone
 David              London                Car
 Ali                Istanbul            Computer
 Arda               Istanbul            Telephone
```

The problem is that:

There are Customer John and Mehmet in Table_1 but not Table_2.
What are John's Requests in Table_1? They are Car and House.
Who wants Car or House and hometown is London in Table_2? It is David.
What is Mehmet's Requests in Table_1? It is Telephone.
Who wants Telephone and hometown is Istanbul in Table_2? It is Arda.
Shortly, I want the customer equivalents of the customers which exist in table_1 but not table_2 where their hometowns and requests in table_2 are the same.
So I want to see this table:

```
 Customer_Table_1     Customer_Table_2    Hometown     Request
 -------------------------------------------------------------
     John                  David           London       Car
     Mehmet                Arda            Istanbul     Telephone
```

I made it in SQL and I saw this table, I used Pivot. But I want to use PL/SQL and I don't know how do it.
How can I do that in PL/SQL?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: What is your question?  Your explanation doesn't really help.

Comment: Shortly I want  common Requests between Table_1 and Table_2.

Comment: If you're already able to do this in SQL, what is it you want to do in PL/SQL? If you want to use the values in PL/SQL to do something with, you can use a cursor, a for loop or even a select into.

Comment: but Hometown is also common. Customer_Table_1 is that Customer is exist Table_1 but don't exist Table_2.

Comment: _"But I want to use PL/SQL and I don't know how do it."_ Then you need to learn some PL/SQL basics. If you already know pivot and inner join in SQL then PL/SQL will be a piece of cake. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info has list of excellent resources for beginners.

Comment: @GordonLinoff   Shortly, I want the customer equivalents of the customers which exist in table_1 but not table_2 where their hometowns and requests in table_2 are the same.

Comment: @user272735 Thanks for your advice. I know basics but I need an algorithm I don't know how set it.

Comment: Hi Yilmaz,  perhaps this will help you understand why the forum volunteers are doubtful about your request. It is similar to this: "We know how to wash dishes, we used water and detergent. But now we also want to use a hammer. How can I use a hammer to wash dishes?" What does your mentor want? If he is a good mentor, he should teach you to NEVER use PL/SQL when a simple, elegant, efficient solution exists in plain SQL. Perhaps he simply wants you to put your SQL function in a procedure to be used on other, similar table situations? Can you clarify? (Perhaps ask your mentor first?)

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved by a simple `INNER JOIN`

```
select a.Customer, b.Customer, a.hometown, a.request
  from table_1 a inner join table_2 b
    on a.hometown = b.hometown and
       a.request  = b.request;
```

Comment: I did it, I use pivot and join. But I want to make procedure or fuction in plsql.

Comment: and what is the goal of the function or procedure?

Comment: my mentor wants to satisfy himself

Comment: @yilmazosmanfurkan61 your mentor clearly knows this then. Why don't you ask from him ? Or is this a homework ?

Comment: @yilmazosmanfurkan61 look for pipelined functions. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#CIHDGJAF

Comment: yesterday I did it using pivot and join in sql and now, he want plsql. I am an intern.